# Call a function within a class

Tags: php

I have the below code snippet which allows me to submit a url, an order type and a quantity via an API but I am struggling to use the function "order", within class "OrderSubmit".
I have tried this but it doesn't work:
`order(http://testurl.com, 1, 100);`

Do I need any particular extra code to use the function because it is within a class? Any other tips where I am going wrong?

```
class OrderSubmit {
    public $api_url = 'XXX'; // API URL
    public $api_key = 'XXX'; // Your API key

    /**
    * Place an order
    */
    public function order($link, $type, $quantity) { // Add order
        return json_decode($this->connect(array(
            'key' => $this->api_key,
            'action' => 'add',
            'link' => $link,
            'type' => $type,
            'quantity' => $quantity
            )));
    }

    /**
    * Get Order Status
    */
    public function status($order_id) { 
        return json_decode($this->connect(array(
            'key' => $this->api_key,
            'action' => 'status',
            'id' => $order_id
            )));
    }

    /**
    * Send post request
    */
    private function connect($post) {
        $_post = Array();
        if (is_array($post)) {
            foreach ($post as $name => $value) {
                $_post[] = $name.'='.urlencode($value);
            }
        }
        $ch = curl_init($this->api_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        if (is_array($post)) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, join('&', $_post));
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)');
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if (curl_errno($ch) != 0 && empty($result)) {
            $result = false;
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }
}

$reseller = new OrderSubmit();
$response = $reseller -> order($link, $type, $quantity); //place an order
$response = $reseller -> status($orderid); // get the status
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what you mean by "doesn't work"? Is there an error? In your code it shows `order($link, $type, $quantity);` but above you said that you tried `order(http://testurl.com, 1, 100);`. If you hard-coded those values for testing, you need to put the URL in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the code at the bottom? Try adding the following above those lines:

```
$link = "http://testurl.com";
$type = 1;
$quantity = 100;

$reseller = new OrderSubmit();
$response = $reseller -> order($link, $type, $quantity); //place an order
$response = $reseller -> status($orderid); // get the status
```

To use any of the functions in the OrderSubmit class, you need to create an OrderSubmit object, which happens in the following line:

```
$reseller = new OrderSubmit();
```

Any actions/functions are then called on the `$reseller` variable.

Comment: If I did the above, what code would submit the order?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does work properly.

I returned `json_encode` array within connect() function to show you if its returned properly, it did print the results. Using `var_dump()` to see its contents.

I would check the url/api you are connecting to be sure its a proper JSON. As for the code itself you've supplied, its correct for calling a function within a class.

example code

```
class OrderSubmit {
 public $api_url = 'XXX'; // API URL
 public $api_key = 'XXX'; // Your API key

/**
 * Place an order
 */
public function order($link, $type, $quantity) { // Add order
  return json_decode($this->connect(array(
    'key' => $this->api_key,
    'action' => 'add',
    'link' => $link,
    'type' => $type,
    'quantity' => $quantity
  )));
}

/**
 * Get Order Status
 */
public function status($order_id) { 
  return json_decode($this->connect(array(
    'key' => $this->api_key,
    'action' => 'status',
    'id' => $order_id
  )));
}

/**
 * Send post request
 */
private function connect($post) {
  return json_encode(array('id'=>2));
}}

$reseller = new OrderSubmit();
$response = $reseller->order('http://test.com', 1, 100); //place an order
// $response = $reseller -> status($orderid); // get the status

var_dump($response);
```

in my example, returning

```
 object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["id"]=> int(2) }
```